# Optimizing an OpenGL ES operation?

Tags: opengl-es, embedded

I'm using the following code to draw characters on screen (each UTF8 character is a texture):

```
int row = 0;

glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

for (StdStr* line in _lines) {
    const char* str = [line cString];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        ((XX::OGL::GLESContext*)context)->viewport(C_WIDTH*i,
                                                   C_HEIGHT*row,
                                                   C_WIDTH,
                                                   C_HEIGHT);

        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[0] + *(str + i));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);  
    }

    row++;
}
```

When there are a lot of characters, the code takes longer to run. In this case, **almost 99%** of the time is spent in the `glDrawArrays` routine. Is it possible to minimise the amount of calls to `glDrawArrays`? *The OpenGL ES version is 1.1.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think that you should try to limit the amount of calls to `viewport`, `glBindTexture` and `glDrawArrays`.

Technically, you should pack all your characters in a single texture, so that you can bind it once.

Then, you could compute the vertices and texcoords in a loop like you do actually, but doing the viewport maths yourself, and accumulating results in a CPU array. Once your array constituted, you should submit a draw call once, providing this array.

You can probably find inpiration here:

http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/oglbmfont/